# What noun should I use when I want "seekability"?

Tags: nouns, terminology, word-usage, programming

This is programming lingo and apparently not a word in the dictionary and so I would like to be able to solve "this problem" with only dictionary primitives.  (If you allow me to speak that away.)

A desired property of random number generators is seekability.  What is it?  If you think of a procedure that produces a sequence of numbers, you can imagine some such procedures will allow you to say "jump ahead 100 hundreds, please" and others would not because they don't have this ability.

Some possibly relevant synonyms of "to seek" are "fun after", "go after".

Here's an attempt.

> A desired property in random number generators is *seekability*, the ability
>   to skip ahead or jump back a certain number of elements in the sequence produced

As you can see, it seems unavoidable to explain what the word is because that is probably the right lingo among experts and I think I would commit a crime if I somehow avoid the word completely.

Comment: Isn’t this actually *seed*ability?

Comment: @Laurel I think what the OP is asking for is a random number generator (RNG) that can index or step forwards and backwards through its sequence of outputs. So you could ask it for the 10th random number from the last one. That is apply its algorithm 10 times and tell you the result. I would call this **indexable**. However in practical terms whilst you can index forwards easily, going backwards can, in general, only be done by storing all the numbers generated so far. RNGs tend to be one way functions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is seeking a term in computer programming not English.

Comment: @PeterJennings I've never heard of needing to *seek* a random number. You simply have one generated. There's no point in generating ten if you only need one. On the other hand, you ***do*** *seed* random numbers. While I understand what's being asked for, it's a bizarre example. It's not the generation of the random number itself that involves seeking. It's the index that involves seeking—the already-generated random number will determine the element picked.

Comment: @JasonBassford I completely agree. One random number should be just as good as any other. This is a pretty pointless requirement. If you want a sequence of numbers from which you can pick any one you desire then it shouldn't be part of the RNG. But this is taking us into the realms of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Within the domain and context, it is a valid word and apt for use. Go ahead.

Comment: @Laurel No. See the context again.

Comment: Any pseudo-random sequence generator that accepts a seed will have this property. The sequence that follows a given seed is unique, otherwise the seed would have no purpose. In effect, the generator maps a sequence of integers onto (typically) a sequence of integers that has certain statistical properties. “Jumping” is always possible through the trivial mechanism of operating the generator. However, one can also imagine the creation of a map that relates an integer position to an integer in the pseudo-random sequence.  This is simply a matter of programming. @Laurel is essentially correct.